# ColorCode of (default) focus in Android

Tags: android

What is the exact color code used in Android(i.e. by default) for state-focus and state-pressed.(Its orange family , but what is the color code !)
Where in the source code of Android its defined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that for state-pressed and state-focused , android used 9 patch image , It can be found in android-sdk/platforms/android-8/data/res/drawable-hdpi/btn_default_selected.9.png , copying this image to my project and using it as a bg for state-focused gets me the desired color , so its not color it is a 9 patch image.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Android has many different implementations, so there is no standard color. Maybe if you said why you needed this we could come up with a better answer for you. As a general guidance (I'm not sure where to look for these colors) you won't find colors defined in the Android source code but in a theme.xml file somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

you can add any number of colors from color code either through xml files or by adding it in drawable(ie by xml file.defining as state-focused or by state-pressed)

Comment: Yep , I have done that ! , but I want default color orange , I have textview which does not get this default focus color !(infact no focus color), I have set android:focusable= true , I can do that using state-focused and state-pressed , but just realized , Though I can set the color , the color set on focus by default has some gradient across edges , Android render it differently !